# Using Pandas .loc to apply new value to multiple row_indexer

Tags: pandas

I have a list of index(2 or more) and I want to use `.loc` only on that indexes

for eg:

- `df` is the dataframe where I want to apply `.loc`
- `df2.index` is the list of index I want to use in `df` to apply new value

`df2.index` looks like this:

```
Int64Index([6, 12, 27, 57, 64, 88, 92, 94, 107], dtype='int64', length=9)
```

**What did I do?**

```
df[df2.index, 'subscribed'] = 'Y'
```

but since `df2.index` is a list of index like this:

```
Int64Index([6, 12, 27, 57, 64, 88, 92, 94, 107], dtype='int64', length=9)
```

it gives me the following warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I checked on multiple random row value and it did what I intended but I got the `!warning`

It seems `.loc` only works on a single row index, not when passing multiple row index

**what I am looking for?**

- I want to use all the index (`df2.index`) and apply new value in `df` on the column `subscribed` but in a proper recommended way... by not getting the `warning` and without putting a flag `warning`
- `df` and `df2` row value has the same index reference

could someone please clarify me how I can achieve the desire result without the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that is exactly (sorry ;)), but I remember having the same issue and wanted to get away the warning and I got it solved by converting the index to a list first.

```
df.loc[df.index.tolist(), 'subscribed'] = 'Y'
```